# How can I install a dependency from source with composer?

Tags: composer-php

While I am developing, there are certain dependencies that I want to have as git clones.

(Partly in case I find bugs and want to submit patches, also because when I'm trying to work things out I pepper code with debug statements, and git lets me clean them all up in one go!).

But all the packages that composer downloads are plain files.

How do I get composer to save packages as git clones? Ideally just some of them, not all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Install all dependencies from source

Run

```
$ composer install --prefer-source
```

to install *all* dependencies from source (where available).

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install:

> **--prefer-source**: There are two ways of downloading a package: `source` and `dist`. For stable versions Composer will use the `dist` by default. The `source` is a version control repository. If `--prefer-source` is enabled, Composer will install from `source` if there is one. This is useful if you want to make a bugfix to a project and get a local git clone of the dependency directly.

#### Install selected dependencies from source

Alternatively, configure *selected* dependencies to be installed from source (or dist) under the `preferred-install` section in `composer.json`:

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "foo/bar": "source",
            "bar/baz": "source",
            "*": "dist"
        }
    }
}
```

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install:

> Defaults to `auto` and can be any of `source`, `dist` or `auto`. This option allows you to set the install method Composer will prefer to use. Can optionally be a hash of patterns for more granular install preferences.